# Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    accountid        VARCHAR(255),
    name             VARCHAR2(255),
    phone_number     INTEGER,
    email_addresses  VARCHAR2(255),
    account_number   VARCHAR(255),
    password         VARCHAR2(255)
);
```

and now i created one procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getaccount (
    param1 IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   SELECT
        accountid,
        password
    FROM
        accounts
    WHERE
        account_number = '||param1) ;
END getaccount;
```

and also why we used || or operator

second i run this code in SQLDEVELOPER
I GET THIS OUT

```
call getaccount('123456');

Call completed.
```

GET THIS MESSAGE

NOW I AM CONNECTING TO JAVA
HERE IS MY CODE IN JAVA

```
CallableStatement pst = Get.connection().prepareCall("{call getAccount(?)}");
                pst.setString(1, Number);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

here Get.connection return Connection .

after i run this i get this error

```
Enter Account Number                       : 123456
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:409)
    at bank.services.SignValidator.getBank(SignValidator.java:20)
    at bank.services.KingobankMain.getBank(KingobankMain.java:49)
    at bank.services.KingobankMain.main(KingobankMain.java:14)
```

Comment: In addition, you need to _clearly_ understand that dbms_output does _not_ write to the screen.  In fact, PL/SQL processes entirely within the server and as _no access to the screen_.  DBMS_OUTPUT only writes to a buffer that is then returned to the caller (sqlplus, etc) _only when the procedure is complete_.  It is then up to that caller to process and display the contents of that buffer.  Some callers completely ignore it, others (like sqlplus) will process it only if directed to do so with the proper SET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure does not return values (output variable ) and you are trying to get data.
This results in an error.

**Stored Procedure OUT Parameters**:

```
reate or replace procedure getaccount (
    p_account_number  in varchar2,
    p_account_id      out varchar2,
    p_password        out varchar2  
) as
  
begin
     select
        accountid,
        password
     into 
        p_account_id,
        p_password
     from
        accounts
     where
        account_number = p_account_number ; 
end getaccount;
/

CallableStatement pst = Get.connection().prepareCall("{call getAccount(?,?,?)}");
                pst.setString(1, "....");//set account number
                pst.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
                pst.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);               
                pst.execute();
        //read the OUT parameter now
                    
                System.out.println("AccountID="+pst.getString(2)+",password="+pst.getString(3));

..........your  of code....
```

**Stored Procedure Oracle SYS_REFCURSOR**:

```
create or replace procedure getaccount (
    p_account_number in varchar2,
    p_cur            out sys_refcursor
) as
  
begin
 open p_cur for 
 select
        accountid,
        password
    from
        accounts
    where
        account_number = p_account_number ;
end getaccount;
/

CallableStatement pst = Get.connection().prepareCall("{call getAccount(?,?)}");
                pst.setString(1, ".....");// set account number
                pst.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                pst.execute();
        //read the OUT parameter now
            rs = (ResultSet) pst.getObject(2);
            
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("AccountID="+rs.getString("accountid")+",password="+rs.getString("password"));
..........your  of code....
}
```

Addition links:

[JDBC Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

[Calling PL/SQL from Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/calling-PL-SQL-from-Java.html#GUID-F2FC29B6-F20F-49FB-99CB-56C9C15ECFB5)

Comment: here i run successfully Cursor type , but i am wonder how to run it in sql in java it is working but i also want to run this in sqldeveloper Please

Comment: in java i am getting OUtput 
but in SQLplus error

Comment: how to run this in sqlPlus please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java, but: procedure you wrote results in output displayed on the screen, but only if tool you used to call the procedure supports it - e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD and similar. For the rest, there will be no result at all.

It looks as if you wanted to run

```
select accountid, password from accoutns where account_number = 123456
```

in Java. You should then use a **function** instead of a procedure. It should return a `VARCHAR2` (that `select` statement) and then you'd execute it in Java. How? Can't tell; as I said, I don't know Java. In Oracle, you'd use dynamic SQL.

Or, if it has to be a procedure, then it should have an `OUT` parameter so that it returns that `select` statement to the caller. But, caller then has to have "something" (a variable?) to accept that output into.

---

As you requested, a procedure with an `OUT` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getaccount (param1     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                        par_query     OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   par_query :=
         'SELECT  accountid,  password  FROM  accounts WHERE '
      || ' account_number = '
      || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_literal (param1);
END getaccount;
```

Note `dbms_assert`, which is used to prevent SQL injection.

---

In order to run it in Oracle, you'd have to use a PL/SQL block with a variable that accepts the result returned by that procedure.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure getaccount (param1     in     varchar2,
  2                                          par_query     out varchar2)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5     par_query :=
  6           'SELECT  accountid,  password  FROM  accounts WHERE '
  7        || ' account_number = '
  8        || dbms_assert.enquote_literal (param1);
  9  end getaccount;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_out varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    getaccount('12345', l_out);
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Result is: ' || l_out);
  6  end;
  7  /
Result is: SELECT  accountid,  password  FROM  accounts WHERE  account_number = '12345'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Apparently, you don't want to return a command represented as a string, but result that is produced by that `select` statement. As commented, consider returning a refcursor. Moreover, use a function instead of a procedure; they are designed to "return" a value. If it is a procedure, you'll have to create OUT parameter(s) and accept their values into *something* (local variables, probably).

Suppose this is table's contents:

```
SQL> select * From accounts;

 ACCOUNTID PASSWORD   ACCOUNT_NUMBER
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 my_pwd     12345

SQL>
```

Function that returns refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function getaccount (param1 in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7           'SELECT  accountid,  password  FROM  accounts WHERE '
  8        || ' account_number = '
  9        || dbms_assert.enquote_literal (param1);
 10    return l_rc;
 11  end getaccount;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select getaccount('12345') from dual;

GETACCOUNT('12345')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

 ACCOUNTID PASSWO
---------- ------
         1 my_pwd


SQL>
```

Or, a procedure with 2 OUT parameters:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure getaccount
  2    (param1  in  varchar2,
  3     p_accid out varchar2,
  4     p_pwd   out varchar2) is
  5  begin
  6    select accountid,  password
  7      into p_accid, p_pwd
  8    from  accounts
  9    where account_number = param1;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_id  varchar2(20);
  3    l_pwd varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    getaccount('12345', l_id, l_pwd);
  6    dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || l_id ||', PWD = ' || l_pwd);
  7  end;
  8  /
ID = 1, PWD = my_pwd

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: can you write it with out parameter 
i am new into oracle , before i used MySQL happily
but MYSQL and oracle are too different

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable replay 
i am very grateful i meet you all guys

Comment: Here you are; I added example of a procedure with an OUT parameter.

Comment: how can i run this sir

Comment: No idea, I don't know Java. In Oracle, you'd create PL/SQL block to do that (because you have to accept OUT parameter's value).

Comment: NO i want it from sqlPlus , it is running in java successfully 
i want to run it in sql developer how can i call 
call getAccounts('123456') something

Comment: OK; I edited the answer and posted what you asked for. Have a look.

Comment: accounId is SELECT  accountid,  password  FROM  accounts WHERE account_number = '123456'  as a output

Comment: how can i execute this

Comment: Smells like dynamic SQL. Search for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Or return a refcursor instead.

Comment: i mean it returning query not result